# How to get returned items

Tags: orders, email, refund

I am trying to edit a credit memo email template. Currently when a credit memo is submitted the template renders all of the products from the order.

```
  <?php $i=0; foreach ($_order->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
       <?php if($_item->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
       <tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? '' : '' ?>>
       <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
       </tbody>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

I need to get the returns data so I can tell the loop to ignore products with the id of any returned items from an order. As far as I can see return details are not included in the order object. So how, using the order id, can I get a list of returned products from an order.

Any alternative methods/suggestions welcome also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the related credit memo details using the order id. Here's the code I used.

```
  $_order = $this->getOrder();
  $orderid = $_order->getId();
  $creditMemos = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_creditmemo_collection');
  $creditMemos->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId);
  $creditMemos->setOrder('created_at','DESC');
  $creditMemos->load();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your need to get the products from an order right? Your logic is allright, remember that as the quote have items on it, respectively tables sales_flat_quote and sales_flat_quote_item, a quote that became an order will have its registers respectively in sales_flat_order and sales_flat_order_item

To get a the product instance from an item you can do **$item->getProduct()**...

I think i dont undestand when you say "return datails", but maybe this infos can help...